# definir posição do cursor

Tags: javascript, ajax

é possível definir onde o cursor irá ficar assim que o usuário entrar em uma tela ?

Por exemplo, tenho esse input, como defino que sempre que a tela for logada ou carregada, o cursor fique nesse input:

```
<input id="itemsearch" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Search">
```

Obrigado

Comment: Determinar a posição do mouse na tela isso não é possível. Use o atributo `autofocus` no seu elemento de entrada para dar a ele um foco quando a página for carregada, ficaria assim `<input id="itemsearch" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Search" autofocus>` ou dependendo do que você esteja fazendo use a função do JavaScript `focus()` no elemento especificado, isso vai dar o mesmo resultado.

Comment: @leandrodonascimento é exatamente isso, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível determinar a posição do cursor (do mouse) em relação à tela. No entanto é possível colocar o foco em determinado campo, que parece ser o que você quer saber. Neste caso, basta executar o seguinte no momento em que precisa determinar o foco:

```
document.getElementById('itemsearch').focus();
```